# Как использовать функцию play() так чтобы не появлялось ошибки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как убрать ошибку: 'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.'

Есть часть кода в которой по нажатию включается аудио(аудио с сервера получаю через axios)

```
const [music, setMusic] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    play()
  }, [music])
  

  function play() {
    new Audio(audioUrl).play()
  }
return(
<>
<button
          onClick={()=>setMusic(music+1)}
            className={styles.audio}
            src={`${'http://localhost:4444'}${audioUrl}`}
            alt="Uploaded"
          />
</>
)
```

Comment: Вы переводили эту ошибку на русский? **Uncaught (в обещании) DOMException: не удалось загрузить, поскольку не найден поддерживаемый источник** При чём тут autoplay() и эта статья? А по поводу, как обойти запрет на autoplay, пока ещё есть хороший вариант: `document.onpointerover =_=> audio.play()` То бишь, когда посетитель заводит курсор на страницу после её обновления кнопкой в браузере, в этот момент начинает играть музыка, хотя кажется, что она запускается автоматически.

Comment: @Опан перепутал ссылку, уже исправил